# What is the point of calculating a standard error?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error

Say I simulate from a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ 10.000 times using a couple of different methods.

I can calculate the standard error as $s/\sqrt{10000}$ where $s$ is the sample standard deviation.

What I don't understand is .... $s$ is the standard deviation of the sample. The sample are generated by simulating a normal distribution. Hence, *by that very fact*, the sample standard deviation of all simulations will be equal to $\sigma$.

So, for **all** my simulation methods, the standard error will be the same. It will be roughly $\sigma /\sqrt{10000}$. So what is the point of *calculating* it? It is already known before-hand and is constant for *all* my simulations, as long as I am simulating the same distribution?

So what is the point of calculating this number? Let me give you an example.

Say you write in R:

```
sample_1 <- rnorm(10000, mu, sigma)

u <- runif(10000)
sample_2 <- qnorm(u)
```

Now, both sample_1 and sample_2 are 10.000 simulations from a $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ distribution... In either case, the standard error will roughly be $\sigma/\sqrt{10.000}$. This number seems pointless to me. It tells me nothing about the relative performance of $sample_1$ vs $sample_2$ ....the standard error is the same?

Comment: In many cases you have the sample but never know $\mu$ or $\sigma$.  You then use $\bar x$ to estimate $\mu$, and use $s / \sqrt{n}$ to estimate the magnitude of the possible error in making that estimate of $\mu$

Comment: @Henry , I think that's the answer.  You might convert that comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

*As requested in comments:*

In many cases you have the sample but never know $\mu$ or $\sigma$.

You then use ${\bar x}$ to estimate $\mu$, and use $s / \sqrt{n}$ to estimate the magnitude of the possible error in making that estimate of $\mu$

Comment: But why use $s$ when you know $\sigma$?

Comment: @Dave If you know $\mu$ then this is all irrelevant.  If you know $\sigma$ but not $\mu$ (how?) then use $\bar x$ and then $\sigma / \sqrt{n}$ for the standard error.  If you know neither  $\mu$  nor $\sigma$ then use $\bar x$ and  then $s / \sqrt{n}$ for the estimate of the standard error

Comment: Z-test has known $\sigma$ and unknown $\mu$.